# using two instance of a class in a button-click event give me error

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a table named `tbl_search` by three columns `id(int) title(string) result(string)`
i create a class named `SearchInGoogle` and write two methods on it, `FindOdd` and`FindEven`, the first method find the record by odd id (1,3,5,7,9,...) and then search `its Title` in Google and put the result on `result`, the second method do something like first method but for record by even id (2,4,6,8,10,...) :

```
 public class SearchInGoogle
{
    GoogleEntities db = new GoogleEntities();

    public void FindOdd()
    {

        List<tbl_search> _oddSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id % 2) != 0).ToList();
        var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");

        foreach (var item in _oddSearchList)
        {
            var results = client.Search(item.title, 1);

            tbl_search _saveSearchResult = _oddSearchList.Where(x => x.id == item.id).FirstOrDefault();
            _saveSearchResult.result = results.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }

    public void FindEven()
    {

        List<tbl_search> _evenSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id % 2) == 0).ToList();
        var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");
        foreach (var item in _evenSearchList)
        {
            var results = client.Search(item.title, 1);
            tbl_search _saveSearchResult = _evenSearchList.Where(x => x.id == item.id).FirstOrDefault();
            _saveSearchResult.result = results.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
}
```

i create two `Thread` and two instance from `SearchInGoogle class` in Form1.cs and for `button-click` event i start the Thread:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GoogleEntities db = new GoogleEntities();
    Thread th1;
    Thread th2;
    SearchInGoogle _sin = new SearchInGoogle();
    SearchInGoogle _sin2 = new SearchInGoogle();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(update));

    }   
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        th1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_sin.FindOdd));
        th2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_sin2.FindEven));
        th1.Start();
        th2.Start();
    }

}
```

but when i click on button it give me error `NullReferenceException`! how can i fix it?

Comment: `it give me error` :) How about posting the exception you get?

Comment: You are using `.FirstOrDefault()` twice in each method. This method can return `null`, so how about adding some checks to see if that is the case?

Comment: I see a lot of redundant code in your class `SearchInGoogle`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a single resource from multiple threads without locking. You are doing:

```
      db.SaveChanges();
```

With any of the two threads and this will make the application fail. You need to lock the access to a single resource by different threads. You are using FirstOrDefault as well and this will fail when calling ToString() if the result is null. Do it like this:

```
 public class SearchInGoogle
{
    GoogleEntities db = new GoogleEntities();
    object dbLock = new object();

    public void FindOdd()
    {

        List<tbl_search> _oddSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id % 2) != 0).ToList();
        var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");

        foreach (var item in _oddSearchList)
        {
            var results = client.Search(item.title, 1);

            tbl_search _saveSearchResult = _oddSearchList.First(x => x.id == item.id);
            _saveSearchResult.result = results.First().ToString();

            lock(dbLock)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

    }

    public void FindEven()
    {

        List<tbl_search> _evenSearchList = db.tbl_search.Where(c => (c.id % 2) == 0).ToList();
        var client = new GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.com");
        foreach (var item in _evenSearchList)
        {
            var results = client.Search(item.title, 1);
            tbl_search _saveSearchResult = _evenSearchList.First(x => x.id == item.id);
            _saveSearchResult.result = results.First().ToString();
            lock(dbLock)
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


    }
}
```